# Why doesn't it show me the time in Canada?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm new to the bigquery worlds and I'm start experimenting with different codes. This is not a professional question, only for beginners like me - and still, I would love for someone to help me.

I made this code:

```
SELECT 
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AT TIME ZONE 'Israel') AS ISR_TIMEZON,
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()AT TIME ZONE 'Canada') AS CANADA_TIMEZON,
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) AS UTC_TIMEZON;
```

When they run it on Israel - it works, but if I add another country - like Canada - it writes that it is a mistake. I also tried a specific area in Canada, for example Quebec, but it did not work. Anyone know why?

Comment: Canada doesn't have just one time zone -- which one do you expect to get?

Comment: I know Canada has a number of time zones ... I meant a specific time zone in Canada, say Montreal. Montreal is in Quebec so I wrote "Quebec" in the code, but even that does not give me a result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try "America/Halifax". If it works, refer to the [table of timezones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

Answer (score 0):

Both Canada and Quebec cover multiple timezones, so the request makes no sense.

- https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/canada/quebec-province

Start here for advice...

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timezone_definitions

That links to Wikipedia's list of international timezone labels.  You need to pick from that list. Specifying arbitrary country names, province names, etc, just won't work.